# Validates doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am new in ruby and like the syntax! But i keep getting this error, can someone tell me why? I did also try to include it with include ActiveModel::Validations without any luck. Getting this "stack level too deep"

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index

 if params[:username]
     l = Users.new(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email]).save
     z = Users.where(:username => params[:username]).limit(1).last
     @debugging = "Howdy" + z[:username] + ""
 end
end
end
```

users model:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :username, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in your model if you are using `active record`:

```
 validates :username, :presence => true
```

It should be `User < ActiveRecord::Base`:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, :presence => true  #or you can also write as 'validates_presence_of :username'

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
end
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:username]
     l = User.new(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email])
     if l.save?
       flash[:success] = "Valid user"
     else
       flash[:error] = "Invalid user"
     end

     z = User.where(:username => params[:username]).limit(1).last
     @debugging = "Howdy" + z[:username] + ""
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When i insert it into my model i keep getting "Stack Level Too Deep"?

Comment: What are using `active model` or `active record`?

Comment: It is "Users" not "User". and the name is  users.rb

Comment: When you use `users` as model name active_record will look for `userss` table in database I think which doesn't exist. To avoid errors you to use `set_table_name "users"` in model. But its better to use rails standard or default things to use to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your model seems ok

Try to change your index action for this:

```
if params[:username]
  user = User.create(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email])
  if user.persisted?
    @debugging = "Howdy #{user.username}"
  else
    @debugging = "Error while creating user"
  end
end
```

If the user is not valid **User.create** will create an User object not **persisted** in database